# Großer offener Bereich am oberen Ende einer Treppe

Tags: single-word-request

Manchmal gibt es in Häusern am oberen Ende einer Treppe einen Bereich, von dem die Türen in die Zimmer abgehen. Hier sind zwei Beispiele von einer Stockfoto-Agentur:

[Beispiel 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ao5X.jpg)

[Beispiel 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbA4C.jpg)

Auf der Webseite der Fotoagentur wird dieser Berreich "Vorraum" genannt. Manchmal ist dieser Bereich aber auch offen zur Treppe oder zum unteren Stockwerk hin und kein wirklicher "Raum".

Wie nennt man so etwas?

Unter "Vorraum" stelle ich mir eigentlich etwas anderes vor ...

Comment: Please add a reference to your image source and make sure their copyright license allows that we publish them here. Until then I replaced the image links with a placeholder. Thank you. For more also see https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/how-do-i-find-images-that-can-be-published-here

Answer (score 9):

<sup>**Hinweis:** Die Frage wurde geändert. Ursprünglich zeigte sie ein drittes Bild mit einer klassischen Galerie, wie sie im Buche steht (balkonartig mit großem Treppenaufgang, Holzgeländer, etc.). Ich halte meine Antwort auch nach der Änderung für richtig.</sup>

---

Ich würde solche Flure spezifischer als *Galerie* bezeichnen.

#### Belege

Laut dem [DWDS (Eintrag *Galerie*, Bedeutung 1a)](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Galerie) handelt es sich bei einer *Galerie* um einen

> „Rundgang am oder im Haus, der an einer Seite offen und mit einem Geländer versehen oder durch Säulen abgetrennt ist“.

Ein Architekturlexikon besitze ich nicht; aber dem Wunsch eines Kommentators, den Begriff durch ein Zitat aus [Wikipedia (Eintrag *Galerie (Architektur)*)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerie_(Architektur)) zu belegen, kann ich nachkommen:

> „Eine Galerie [...] bezeichnet in der Architektur im weitesten Sinne eine Räumlichkeit, die länger als breit ist und an mindestens einer ihrer beiden Längsseiten zahlreiche Lichtöffnungen besitzt.“

Zudem möchte ich eine Definition des Begriffes [*Galeriewohnung* (Immonet)](https://www.immonet.de/galeriewohnung.html) anführen:

> „Eine Galeriewohnung erstreckt sich nämlich über zwei Etagen, wobei diese aber nicht geschlossen sind. Vom oberen Raum der Galeriewohnung aus kann man, quasi wie von einem Balkon, in den unteren Raum gucken und natürlich andersherum.“

Weitere Belege sind in den Kommentaren zu finden.

Comment: Wobei nur das dritte Bild eine klassische "Galerie" zeigt. Das erste ist (wie @Pollitzer in seiner Antwort richtig schreibt) einfach nur ein Flur, das zweite ist nicht klar zu erkennen.

Comment: Ich stimme vor allem dieser Antwort zu. Aber wie wäre es, dies mit einem Zitat aus einem Architekturlexikon (WP geht anscheinend nicht) zu belegen? (Sprachgefühl sagt mit, dass Galerien in relativ kleinen Häusern meist ein Geländer haben und dann Teil des Erschließungsraumes namens Flur sind.) So hab ich das jedenfalls in Grundrissen gelesen. In großen Gebäuden trifft dann die Definition aus DWDS zu.

Comment: Hier noch zwei Links, um die Belege etwas ausbauen zu können: [Galerie-Häuser](https://www.bautipps.de/news/galerie-haeuser) und [Die Galerie](https://www.schwoererhaus.de/ihre-vorteile/hausausstattung/galerien/).

Comment: Ich habe das irreführende dritte Bild gelöscht. Ich meine kelne Galerie, wie die anderen beiden Bilder deutlich machen.

Comment: Das ist aus zweierlei Gründen ungünstig: (1) Meine Antwort bezog sich von vorn herein auf alle drei Bilder. Auch auf den ersten beiden sehe ich Galerien &ndash; keine klassischen, die mit großen Treppenaufgängen und Holzgeländern wie Balkone wirken, aber dennoch Galerien. Zumal die Wohnungen Galeriewohnungen per Definition sind, was keinen Sinn ergäbe, wenn Sie diese Flure nicht als Galerie bezeichnen wollen.

Comment: (2) Ihre ursprüngliche Frage hat 5 Antworten, und nun haben Sie sie an einer entscheidenden Stelle geändert. In ein paar Tagen ist nicht mehr nachvollziehbar, welche Antwort sich auf welche Frageversion bezieht oder wie wir auf unsere Antworten gekommen sind.

Answer (score 4):

Das ist meiner Meinung nach ganz banal der *obere Treppenabsatz*. In einem Immobilien-Exposé würde man sich allerdings möglicherweise was "Edleres" oder ein paar Attribute wie "großzügig" und "geräumig" einfallen lassen.

Answer (score 3):

Mich wundert, dass noch niemand

> Diele

genannt hat.

Zwar liegt die normalerweise hinter der Eingangstür, baulich sehe ich neben dem Abstand zum Erdboden aber keinen entscheidenden Unterschied.

Architekt [Volker Kugel](https://www.bauexpertenforum.de/threads/unterschied-zwischen-flur-und-diele.22293/#post-224624) sagt allerdings:

> Üblicherweise bezeichnet man den Eingangsbereich hinter der
>   Haus-/Wohnungstür als Diele und alle anderen Verkehrsbereiche als
>   **Flur**.

Das Fachwort dürfte also »Flur« sein.

Comment: Flur trifft es glaube ich ganz gut.

Comment: Für mich ist ein (Haus-)Flur lediglich ein Verbindungsraum zwischen anderen Räumen und die Diele ist der Hausflur hinter der Eingangstür. Auch ein treppenloser Bungalow kann eine Diele und einen Flur haben.

Comment: @Takkat: Vielleicht ist es so, dass »Flur« der Oberbegriff ist und »Diele«, »Galerie« und »Empore« spezielle Flur-Arten sind.

Comment: Da müßte man wirklich einen Architekten fragen, aber wenn mich jemand nach einem "großen offenen Bereich am oberen Ende einer Treppe" fragte, käme ich nicht als erstes auf "Flur".

Answer (score 2):

Ich schlage

> [Treppenkopf](http://baulexikon.deacademic.com/4493/Treppenkopf)

vor, das findet sich auch in richtiger Literatur, wie Thomas Manns Tonio Kröger:

> Droben, in den großen Zimmern hinter der Säulenhalle, wohnten fremde Leute, er sah es; denn der Treppenkopf war durch eine Glastür verschlossen, ...

Comment: Der Treppenkopf ist nur das obere Ende der Treppe, nicht der an die Treppe anschließende Raum. So haben auch eine auf einem Tieflader liegende oder eine freistehende Treppe ohne Gebäude drumherum einen Treppenkopf.

Comment: Siehe z.B. Text und Abbildung auf Seite 7 oben hier: https://www.yumpu.com/de/document/view/22369533/broschure-downloaden-dennert-baustoffwelt/6 oder: "Zur Vermeidung von Schallbrücken zwischen Treppenkopf bzw. -fuß und Podestplatte oder Geschossdecke eignet sich ...", was den Treppenkopf klar von der Geschossdecke unterscheidet.

Answer (score 0):

Angesichts dessen, dass der Raum in um das Treppenoberende (oder den Treppenkopf) herum in diesem Bildern als Verteilerebene für den Zugang zu weiteren Räumen dient, finde ich das Wort

> Vestibül

hier passend, auch wenn ein Vestibül zunächst nichts mit Treppen zu tun hat sondern eben einen Raum darstellt, der kein enger Flur oder Korridor ist, sondern offener geformt ist, und von dem aus man andere Räume erreicht.

Eventuell könnte man zur Präzisierung

> Treppenvestibül

sagen, oder, noch etwas aufwendiger

> Obergeschoß-Vestibül

Sollte der Zweck der Übung sein, in einer Immobilienanzeige in die  schwülstige Maklerwerbesprache zu einzufallen, dann ist "Vestibül" jedenfalls eine gute Wahl, denn üblicherweise spricht man von "Vestibül" bei großen, herrschaftlichen Häusern oder Schlössern.

Comment: Ist das Vestibül aber nicht hinter der Eingangstür?